# How/where is wordpress including jquery in the header of my file?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, include

Wordpress is somehow including jquery in the header of my site. I already have jquery manually installed, and would prefer to turn off the extra inclusion.

It doesn't seem to be coming from any plugins. Does anyone have any ideas where it may be coming from?

Comment: Can you give url so we can investigate on this further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's automatically called when other scripts dependent on it are called using wp_enqueue_script.

Instead of putting it inline in your header add this to your functions.php

```
add_action( 'init', 'daves_jquery' )
function daves_jquery() {
if (!is_admin() ) {
wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
wp_register_script ( 'jquery', '/path_to_your_jquery/jquery.js', true);
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Chances are, this is being done with a hook, which uses the `add_action` API function. Check the functions.php file in your theme and see if there's anything in there that's doing it.

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API#Hook_to_WordPress for more details on hooks.

Also, if you know what the added action is named, you can remove it by placing code like this in the functions.php file in your theme:

```
remove_action('wp_head', 'wlwmanifest_link');
```

In the example code, this will remove a registered action call `wlwmanifest_link` that was tacked onto the `wp_head` section of the action loop.  Chances are, the `add_action` statement you're looking for that is including jquery will be attached to `wp_head` since that's how you get code inserted there during the loop.